# How to use data from a IWebPartRow connection when Button is clicked. Provider is always null

Tags: sharepoint, null, connection, web-parts

I’m not sure how to explain my problem
I’m trying to implement a WebPart with a webpart connection to listview webparts. For the connection I use the IWebPartRow interface. 
Here is what I want to achieve:
In the list view webpart I can select an Item. In my WebPart details from the connection Provider and a button are displayed. When this button is clicked I want to do something using the data coming from the connection Provider.

Here the webpart code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

namespace ConnectedFilesWebPart.TestWebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class TestWebPart : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {

        public DataRowView DataRow
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }

        public IWebPartRow Provider
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private readonly StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            //TestWebPartUserControl control = (TestWebPartUserControl)Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
            Button myButton = new Button();
            myButton.Text = "myButton";
            myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
            Controls.Add(myButton);
        }

        protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (DataRow != null)
            {
                int lookupId = Int32.Parse(DataRow["ID"].ToString());
                string title = DataRow["Title"].ToString();
            }
        }

        private void GetRowData(object rowData)
        {
            try
            {
                DataRow = (DataRowView)rowData;
            }
            catch
            {
                DataRow = null;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Provider != null)
                Provider.GetRowData(new RowCallback(GetRowData));
        }

        [ConnectionConsumer("Row", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
        public void ReceiveProvider(IWebPartRow p)
        {
            Provider = p;
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.RenderContents(writer);
            if (DataRow != null)
            {
                DataRow providerRow = DataRow.Row;
                foreach (DataColumn column in providerRow.Table.Columns)
                    _sb.AppendFormat("- data column: {0} = {1}\n", column.ColumnName ?? "n/a", providerRow[column]);
                _sb.Append("\n");
                writer.Write(_sb.ToString().Replace("\n", "<br>"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the webpart is loaded, the connection works fine. But for some reason when I click the button in myButton_Click the object DataRow is allways null. It seems to me as if the webpart is loaded again but the provider is not called this time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing. I found a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx) on MSDN that looks like it will connect the dots (for you and for me!). Hope this helps.

Edit: An even better answer can be found [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=678). It is doing something similar to what you're trying to do, and it works! There is downloadable code, too!